# Windows 8.1 installation

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

I recently purchased a 1TB Toshiba MQ01ABD100 hdd for my Samsung NP530U laptop. I was installing Windows 8.1 on the hdd using an USB drive. During this process the laptop restarts several times so after the first restart it did not boot from the hdd and its stuck there.

I have disabled the Fast Bios mode and the hdd has the highest boot priority followed by the USB. Please tell me how can I get past this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using [Windows To Go](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/devices/windowstogo.aspx) which is a feature of Windows 8.1 Enterprise, Windows 8.1 doesn't actually support booting from USB without installing a load of hacks which I would recommend against.

Sorry!

Comment: "I was installing Windows 8.1 on the hdd using a USB drive",  it is a USB install source, I believe.